# I am getting stuck on white screen in react App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am learning React native and was trying to build an app. However, the app is stuck on a white screen and doesn't show anything nor gives any error.

The components in the app gets displayed for a second then again vanishes. Please suggest some modifications to rectify the problem

App.js

```
    import React,{useEffect,createContext,useReducer,useContext, useState} from 'react';
    import NavBar from './components/Navbar'
    import "./App.css"
    import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch,useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
    import Home from './components/screens/Home'
    import Signin from './components/screens/Signin'
    import Profile from './components/screens/Profile'
    import Signup from './components/screens/Signup'
    import CreatePost from './components/screens/CreatePost'
    import {reducer,initialState} from './reducers/userReducer'
    
    
    export const UserContext = createContext()
    
    
    const Routing = ()=>{
      const history = useHistory()
      const {state,dispatch} =useContext(UserContext)
      useEffect(()=>{
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
        
    if(user){
      dispatch({type:"USER",payload:user})
    }
    else{
      history.push('/signin')
    }
 

     },[])
      return(
    
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" >
     <Home />
     </Route>   
   <Route path="/signin" >
     <Signin />
   </Route>
   <Route path="/signup" >
     <Signup />
   </Route>
   <Route path="/profile" >
     <Profile />
   </Route>
   <Route path="/create" >
     <CreatePost/>
   </Route>
   </Switch>

       
      )
    }

    function App() {
      const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)
      return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{state,dispatch}}>
        <BrowserRouter >
       <NavBar />
        <Routing />
        </BrowserRouter>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

index.js

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
    
   
    reportWebVitals();
```

package.json

```
 {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "proxy": "<http://localhost:5000>",
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-async": "^10.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

navbar.js

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import {Link ,useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import {UserContext} from '../App'
const NavBar = ()=>{
  const {state,dispatch} =useContext(UserContext)
  const history = useHistory()
  const renderList = ()=>{
    if(state){
      return [
        <li><Link to="/profile">Profile</Link></li>,
        <li><Link to="/create">Create Post</Link></li>,
        <li>
        <button className="btn #e53935 red darken-1" 
         onClick={()=>{
           localStorage.clear()
           dispatch({type:"CLEAR"})
           history.push('/signin')
         }
         }
         >
             Logout
                       </button>
     </li>
        
      ]
    }else{
      return [
            <li><Link to="/signin">Signin</Link></li>,
            <li><Link to="/signup">Signup</Link></li>
           
      ]
    }
  }
    return(
        <nav>
        <div className="nav-wrapper white">
          <Link to={state?"/":"/signin"} className="brand-logo left">pixagram</Link>     
          <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right">
           {renderList()}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

Comment: What changed? (please don't say "nothing") "_Previously it was working fine._"

Comment: Showing all the navbar components

Comment: Start here: [Stack Overflow Search Results](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+white+screen+site:stackoverflow.com&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk014f_l71-tW_iyO6XdEsdX1MuXcqw:1612028175672&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw-5z2mMTuAhUHQ6wKHff7AoQQrQIoBHoECAEQBQ&biw=1792&bih=929)

Comment: So post this `Navbar` component's code.

Comment: You are using react-dom and react-router-dom in react-native? I thought those were browser only components